# iOS webview ssl Connect (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, webview, https

iOS9.3 xcode7.3.1
I want to use WebView to access a HTTPS site, there was an error(kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://52.197.95.84/ResonaIgonWeb/index.html"]];
request.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
request.timeoutInterval = 7.0;
self.myWebview.delegate = self;
self.myWebview.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.myWebview.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.myWebview.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.myWebview loadRequest:request];
```

When I realized the proxy

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
 {
    NSString* str = request.URL.scheme;
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        if (isOK == NO) {
            originrequest = request;
            NSURLSessionConfiguration* con = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            con.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;
            NSURLSession* urlsession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:con delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
            task = [urlsession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData* _Nullable data, NSURLResponse* _Nullable response, NSError* _Nullable error) {
                NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"%@", str);
            }];
            [task resume];
            [webView stopLoading];
            return NO;
        }
    }
return YES;
 }
```

I have already added in info.list

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    </dict>
```

Is there any way to use HTML to display the XX webView on the server？
please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>insecure.example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: NSURLSessionTask returned to the HTML document, but the use of WebView loaded request is still wrong .   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)